# Pass a two dimensional array to a function of constant parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc-warning

I learned from *C Primer Plus* that if you want to protect an array from being accidentally modified by a function, you should add `const` modifier before the pointer declaration in the header of function definition.

Following this sensible advice, in the following minimal example, I'm trying to pass a non-constant two-dimensional array `array` to the function `Sum2D`, one parameter of which is a `pointer-to-const-int[2]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 2
int Sum2D(const int ar[][COLS], int rows); //use `const` to protect input array
int main(void)
{
    int array[ROWS][COLS]={{1,2},{3,4}}; //the non-constant array

    printf( "%d\n", Sum2D(array,ROWS) );

    return 0;
}

int Sum2D(const int ar[][COLS], int rows)
{
    int total=0;
    int i,j;
    for( i=0 ; i<rows ; i++ )
    {
        for( j=0 ; j<COLS ; j++ )
        {
            total+=ar[i][j];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

However, `gcc` cannot successfully compile this code without issuing the following warnings:

```
$gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -o test test.c

test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:16:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Sum2D’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  printf( "%d\n", Sum2D(array,4) );
  ^
test.c:4:5: note: expected ‘const int (*)[4]’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[4]’
 int Sum2D(const int ar[][COLS], int rows);
     ^
```

1) Why the warning?

2) How can I eliminate the "noise"?(Apart from adding `const` to `array` declaration.)

(If the `array` and function both use one-dimensional array, there is no warning.)

> System information:
>
> Ubuntu 14.04LTS
>
> Compiler: gcc 4.8.2

Comment: Very straight forward. The function `Sum2D` is expecting to receive a const 2d array but you give it a non const one. This might be dangerous but not necessarily, that's why a warning and not error.

Comment: @inneedofhelp Actually, the function expects a *pointer* to a size COLS array of `const int`. In a function parameter, `const int ar[][COLS]` is the same as `const int (*ar)[COLS]`

Comment: Any reason for your parameter `rows` is there rather than just using the defined dimension?

Comment: Apparently gcc had a field day with their warnings. [4.9.2 shows no such warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a099d825ec238dfe)

Comment: @inneedofhelp But this is actually an simplified example in the book _C Primer Plus_. It says that assigning a non-const pointer to a const pointer is okay. Because the `const` is for protection. Maybe it is not correct?

Comment: @Mario No, not really. It's just for use with arrays with different row number.

Comment: For the record, this compiles fine with clang, in strict c89, c99 and c11 modes.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well that's somewhat relieving. Thanks for providing result from different version of gcc.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for providing results from clang.

Comment: @juanchopanza and WhozCraig, Do you think this might be a "bug" in gcc 4.8.2? And this should actually be valid? (As it seems to be in gcc 4.9.2.)

Comment: Compilers are allowed to compile non-conforming programs as an extension, so it wouldn't be a serious bug, however it could be annoying if somebody writes code this way and later ports the code to a compiler that doesn't have the extension

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an unfortunate "bug" in C's design; `T (*p)[N]` does not implicitly convert to `T const (*p)[N]`.  You will have to either use an ugly cast, or have the function parameter not accept `const`.

---

At first sight it looks like this conversion should be legal. C11 6.3.2.3/2:

> For any qualifier *q*, a pointer to a non-*q*-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the *q*-qualified version of the type;

However also look at C11 6.7.3/9  (was /8 in C99):

> If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers, the element type is so-qualified, not the array type.

This last quote says that `int const[4]` is **not** considered to be a `const`-qualified version of `int[4]`. Actually it is a non-`const`-qualified array of 4 `const int`s.  `int[4]` and `int const[4]` are arrays of different element types.

So 6.3.2.3/2 does not in fact permit `int (*)[4]` to be converted to `int const (*)[4]`.

---

Another weird situation where this issue with `const` and arrays shows up is when typedefs are in use; for example:

```
typedef int X[5];
void func1( X const x );
void func1( int const x[5] );
```

This would cause a compiler error: `X const x` means that `x` is const, but it is pointing to an array of non-const `int`s; whereas `int const x[5]` means `x` is not const but it is pointing to an array of const ints!

Further reading [here](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/const-and-arrays/), thanks to @JensGustedt

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I wonder if this means clang is "fixing" this as an extension. I tried compiling in strict mode (`-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic-errors  -std=cxx` where `xx` is 89, 99, 11.)

Comment: By ugly cast, do you mean something like `(const int (*)[])`? I did "fix" it by adding this in function call.

Comment: I think my knowledge is still too limited to fully understand what you mean. But when I am trying, I want to ask: Are `const int (*)[4]` and `int const (*)[4]` the same thing? As the former is what I saw in the warning message.

Comment: @Naitree `const int (*)[4]` and `int const (*)[4]` are the same thing; a pointer to an array of four const `int`. *Both* differ from `int (*const)[4]`, a const pointer to an array of four non-const `int`. And lest we leave it out, `int const (*const)[4]`, a const pointer to an array of four const `int`.

Comment: @Naitree And imho, the const-issue of a fixed-declaration of a non-const array of const-qualified elements, per C11 6.7.3/9, is nothing if not pointless. As the array id itself is not an lvalue, the lack of const-ness applied therein shouldn't even be a question. That the compiler pukes a warning on the conversion-to-const-qualified-pointer-to-first-element where other versions of gcc don't makes me go "wtf".

Comment: @MattMcNabb Sorry for bothering you again. Would you mind checking if I understand your point correctly? As I understand, 
the problem is that `const int[4]` means the data type "array-of-4-constant-integer-numbers", rather than "constant-array-of-4-integer-numbers".
A pointer to "array-of-4-integer-numbers"(`int[4]`) may be converted to "constant-array-of-4-integer-numbers", rather than to "array-of-4-constant-integer numbers"(`const int[4]`).

Comment: add "a pointer to" before your last two quoted terms, and then it's ok

Comment: In the latest draft of c23 the text was changed to "If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers, **both** the array and the element type
is so-qualified.". So this issue maybe finally solved

Comment: @tstanisl Great to hear although I suspect not everyone will upgrade to C23 quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can type cast the array while calling the function. It will not automatically convert non-const into const.
You can use this.

```
Sum2D( (const int (*)[])array, ROWS );
```

Comment: I actually still get warning using your typecast. I think what you mean is `(const int (*)[])`. Then the warning is gone.