# Using const with pointer to array in formal parameter

Tags: c, c89

I have a matrix data type and a function with a formal parameter of matrix type. Since the function will not modify its parameter I use a `const` qualifier:

```
typedef int Matrix[2][2];

static void Foo(const Matrix A)
{
    ...
}
```

When I call this function it seems like I need to cast the actual parameter:

```
Matrix A;
...
Foo((const int (*)[2]) A);
```

Without the cast the compiler I use (GCC) will issue a warning:

> warning: pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic]

Is there a different way to approach the problem so that the cast is not necessary?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: @Quentin See updated question.

Comment: Cannot [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/688ca24e9d435bd5)

Comment: Do you have to strictly use gcc? I had no warnings compiling with g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic.

Comment: duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488559/pointer-to-array-with-const-qualifier-in-c-c#34488782](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488559/pointer-to-array-with-const-qualifier-in-c-c#34488782)

Comment: @MichaelWalz I use GCC 6.3.0 with the options `-Wall -pedantic -std=c89`.

Comment: @Jango I'm adhering to ANSI C89. Your command treats the code as C++.