# container_of macro does not work for char* or array members

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am reading Linux Device Drivers Development from John Madieu and one para says

```
The container_of macro won't work for char * or array members. It
means the first member of container_of must not be a pointer to
another pointer to char nor to array in the structure.
```

This is the definition of `container_of` :

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
                const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
                (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

So if I have

```
struct person {
int age;
int salary;
char *name;
} me;
```

and I have `char ** my_name = &(me.name);`, why can't I do the following :

```
struct person * me = container_of(my_name,struct person,name);
```

Comment: Tangential but I assume the author meant to write _"the first **argument** of container_of"_

Comment: yes even I understand that, but still I don't understand why?

Comment: There were changes to `container_of` in kernel version 4.13 to address this problem. I tried your code on kernel version 4.18 and 4.19 and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to ISO C rules on pointer initialisations, which break the initialisation of `__mptr` for this case.

Here's a stripped-back example:

```
int main()
{
    char ar[5] = {0};
    const char (*ptr)[5] = &ar;
}

// warning: pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic]
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9413a62bac51155a))

There is a discussion about this problem on [a prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34488782/560648). Note that [C++ has no such limitation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e341c1c2509b55bb); the `const` may be added freely.

[A kernel dev discussion](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/790486/) suggested replacing `__mptr` with another way to perform the type check inside `container_of`, so you may find that this already no longer affects you.

Comment: A [later version of the patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c7acec713d14c6ce8a20154f9dfda258d6bcad3b) in that kernel dev discussion eventually made it into kernel version 4.13. (Actually, it ended up as the last part of a [series of 6 patches](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/xa1t4lw9hw55.fsf@mina86.com/t/) that I wrote.)