# cast const pointers to void * in C++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I have the following code that does not compile with gcc 10.2.1 :

```
struct Bar {
    unsigned char *m_a;
    unsigned char m_b[1];
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    const Bar &b = bar;

    void *p1 = b.m_a; // Ok
    void *p2 = b.m_b; // Error

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is :

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]

I can fix this by using either `void *p2 = (void *)b.m_b;` or `void *p2 = const_cast<unsigned char *>(b.m_b);` however, constness of members does not seem to be treated the same by the compiler.

I guess there is an "extra-check" for the array and not with the pointer but why is that ?

Thank you.

Comment: In the case of pointer, then the value of the pointer becomes const, and not what it points to. You can modify the unsigned char that it points to, but you cannot make it point to another unsigned char location. When objects are `const`ed, only the top level qualifier of the members will implicitly also be `const`ed

Comment: Use `const void*`. For example `const void *p2 = b.m_b;`. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ChiZjPsko)

Comment: It is the same situation as `const int a[1]; int* p = a;`, and you probably understand why that is bad.

Comment: *why is that?*  Because in C++ `const`-ness is not transitive in most situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a `const` struct adds `const` to all the members.

Adding `const` to `unsigned char *` gives you `unsigned char * const` (i.e., the pointer cannot be changed to point to anything else, but you can change the value of what is pointed to). This can be cast to `void *`, since that is also a pointer to non-`const`.

Adding `const` to `unsigned char[1]` gives you `const unsigned char[1]` (A `const` array of `T` is actually an array of `const T`). This can decay into a `const unsigned char *` pointer, which can be cast to a `const void *`, but not a `void *` without casting away the `const`. This is because the elements of the array cannot be modified, unlike the pointed-at object with the first member.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488559/pointer-to-array-with-const-qualifier-in-c-c also helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
b.m_a
```

This is an `unsigned char *`. It is happy to be converted to a `void *`.

```
b.m_b
```

This is a `const unsigned char *`. That's how arrays work in C and C++: the name of the array decays to a pointer to the first value in the array. This array is `const`, therefore this becomes a `const unsigned char *`, and you can't convert it to a `void *`.

Note that you'll get the same error if you attempt to convert `&b.m_a` to a `void *`.

`b.m_a` itself is `const`, but it's not pointing to a `const` object. These are two very different things: a `const` pointer and a pointer to a `const`.

Comment: `b.m_a` is actually `unsigned char* const`

Answer (score 0):

The expression `b` is of type `const Bar` meaning the data member `m_a` is `unsigned char *const` and `m_b` is `const unsigned char [1]`.

Now, the important thing to note is [that](https://www.amazon.in/C-Primer-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113):

> a pointer to **any nonconst type** can be converted to `void*`, and a pointer to **any type** can be converted to a `const void*`

(emphasis mine)[Source](https://www.amazon.in/C-Primer-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113)

This means that `b.m_a` can be implicitly converted to a `void*` and `b.m_b` can be implicitly converted to `const void*` and not `void*`.

Thus to solve your problem, you should add a low-level const to `p2` as shown below:

```
vvvvv-------------------->low level const added
const void *p2 = b.m_b; // works now
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/y7-XjqK4I)