# C programming with const parameter in function

Tags: c

I have one doubt.
Please see the below C program

```
int main(void){

    unsigned int consttest_var = 1;
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
    consttest_var++;
    consttest_func(consttest_var);  
    }
    return 0;
}

    void consttest_func(const unsigned int consttest_var1){
    printf("\n%d", consttest_var1);
}
```

I tried the above code and I got value for `consttest_var1` as 2,3,4....10. Why `consttest_var1` should print the value when it was declared as const. I was expecting it will throwing error as read only. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I plan to declare time to be constant in a function and see if it stops the system clock.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int consttest_var = 1;
```

here you declared it as non-const.

When you send it to`consttest_func(consttest_var)`, the function expects `const unsigned int` as declared:`void consttest_func(const unsigned int consttest_var1)`

the function itself is not allowed to change the argument, because it is const, but outside of the function's scope, the variable isn't const, hence, can be modified

To sum things up - your functoin expects a const variable, and does not modify it - as it should

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486326/does-const-just-mean-read-only-or-something-more) for further reading about const

Note: declaring a variable as const does not mean you can't modify (as argument) it elsewhere. for example ,this code will compile, even though I get a const and increment it, because although a is defined as `const` what the function f gets is a copy of it, and the copy is modifiable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int a){
a++;
return a;
}

 int main(){
    const int a = 1;
    printf("\n%d",f(a));
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting it will throwing error as read only.

```
void consttest_func(const unsigned int consttest_var1){
    printf("\n%d", consttest_var1);
}
```

Your `consttest_func` never really modifies parameter `consttest_var1`, so no it won't throw any error as read only.

If you actually modify the parameter inside `consttest_func`, such as with statement like `consttest_var1++;` then it will throw `read-only parameter` as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

The const variable `consttest_var1` is declared locally for the function consttest_func. Once the function ends, `consttest_var1` goes out of scope.

When you call the function again, a new space in the stack is allocated for a new `const consttest_var1` which after initialize will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that each time your function is called, a new value is passed to it. And in your program it doesn't matter whether your variable 'consttest_var1' is constant or not, as your function is just displaying the value received.
And a constant variable is a variable whose value cannot be modified once it is initialized. Follow the comments in the program...

```
            int main(void)
            {
                unsigned int consttest_var = 0;
                unsigned int i;
                for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
                consttest_var++;
                consttest_func(consttest_var);
                }
                return 0;
            }
                void consttest_func(const unsigned int consttest_var1)
            {
                consttest_var1=3; //suppose if u write this line.
                /* then this line will throw an error that u were talking about 
                i.e. assignment of read only parameter 
                as u are modifying the value of a constant variable */
                printf("\n%d", consttest_var1);
            }
```