# How does "const" differ in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, constants

How does the const qualification on variables differ in C and C++?

from: [Does "const" just mean read-only or something more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486326/does-const-just-mean-read-only-or-something-more-in-c-c)

"What prompted this question was this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024318#4024417 where he states const "just" means read-only in C. I thought that's all const meant, regardless of whether it was C or C++. What does he mean?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c

Comment: @karlphillip: Not an answer. That lists uses of const in C++, but doesn't list differences in const between C and C++. Completely different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const` in C cannot be used to build constant expressions.

For example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i = 2;
   const int C = 2;
   switch(i)
   {
      case C  : printf("Hello") ;
      break;

      default : printf("World");
   }
}
```

doesn't work in C because case label does not reduce to an integer constant.

Comment: I could be remembering wrong, but I think this is changed in C99.

Comment: @ephemient : Nopes. Check out my answer again.

Answer (score 7):

`const` means that *you* promise not to mutate the variable.  It could still be changed.

```
class A {
  public:
    A(const int& a);
    int getValue() const;
    void setValue(int b);
  private:
    const int& a;
};
A::A(a) : a(a) {}
int A::getValue() const {
    return a;
}
void A::setValue(int b) {
    a = b;  // error
}

int main() {
    int my_a = 0;
    A a(my_a);
    std::cout << a.getValue() << std::endl;  // prints 0
    my_a = 42;
    std::cout << a.getValue() << std::endl;  // prints 42
}
```

No method `A::*` may change `a`, but `main` can.  That much is identical between C and C++.

---

What C++ does have are a couple (limited) ways to bypass `const`, which are supposed to discourage programmers from discarding `const` inappropriately.

Take a class like this.

```
class A {
  public:
    A();
    int getValue();
  private:
    static int expensiveComputation();
    int cachedComputation;
};

A::A() : cachedComputation(0) {}

A::getValue() {
    if (cachedComputation == 0)
        cachedComputation = expensiveComputation();
    return cachedComputation;
}
```

`cachedComputation` implicitly means `this->cachedComputation`.  Keep this in mind.

```
int main() {
    A a1;
    const A a2;
    std::cout << a1.getValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a2.getValue() << std::endl;  // error
}
```

`a2.getValue()` is illegal, because a non-`const` method is being called on a `const A a2`.  One could cast away the `const`-ness…

```
    std::cout << ((A&)a2).getValue() << std::endl;            // C-style cast
    std::cout << const_cast<A&>(a2).getValue() << std::endl;  // C++-style cast
```

The second is preferred, because the compiler will check that only the `const`-ness is being casted, nothing else.  However, this is still not ideal.  Instead, there should be a new method added to the class.

```
class A {
  public:
    int getValue() const;
};

A::getValue() const {
    if (cachedComputation == 0)
        cachedComputation = expensiveComputation();  // error
    return cachedComputation;
}
```

Now there is a `const` method, so `a2.getValue()` is fine.  However, the trailing `const` means that the method is given a `const A *this` pointer, not an `A *this` pointer like usual, making `this->cachedComputation` a `const int &` that cannot be mutated.

`const_cast` could be applied inside the method, but better would be to change this one member's declaration.

```
class A {
  private:
    mutable int cachedComputation;
};
```

Now, even with a `const A *this`, `this->cachedComputation` can be mutated without casting.

Comment: I think your post doesn't answer his question. You haven't written anything about `const` in **C**.

Comment: @ephemient: If you add @Prasoon's bit to your answer, I'll accept it.  Unfortunately, at this point, neither answer completely answers the question, and I believe yours is more complete. (FYI, I did test Prasoon's answer with gcc -std=c99 to be sure he was correct.)

Comment: @Prasoon: He shows that C++ provides a mutable keyword, whereas C doesn't. I think that relates directly to the usage of const within the language, am I wrong? I believe your answer also stated an important difference.

Comment: @Kim : But your question was about `const` not `mutable`. AFAIK the only difference between const in C and C++ is what I have mentioned in my post.

Comment: The call and the implications you show with `const_cast<A&>(a2).getValue()` are not legal. They cause undefined behavior. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: How can a cast-away const of an automatic variable possibly fail?

Comment: @Yttrill: "in theory it's UB" ≠ "in practice it can fail".

Comment: @Yttrill A compiler is probably free to replace it with an immediate value, or put it in read-only memory since it has no (user-defined) destructor and is just an int, or perhaps decorate the memory with a read-only flag to prevent exploits or be more efficient.