# #define a string literal then assign it to a char*

Tags: c, pointers, macros, constants, lint

```
#define MAXSTR "Maximum number reached"

char *str = MAXSTR;
```

While doing this kind of operation. Code is working & running fine but I am getting lint error. How I can resolve it?

```
Error:
Assignment of string literal to variable
```

If I use:

```
 #define MAXSTR "Maximum number reached"

 char *str = (char *) MAXSTR;
```

then lint error:

```
Attempt to cast away const (or volatile)
```

Comment: Do not put a `;` after your macro definition. Otherwise your question is not clear, could you reshape it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between a macro and a const in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393776/difference-between-a-macro-and-a-const-in-c)

Comment: You ask different questions in the title and the question description. Please be clear.

Comment: Sorry for improper description. Corrected some information.

Comment: Please see answers on other questions on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442328/what-is-the-difference-betweem-define-and-const http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274008/why-would-someone-use-define-to-define-constants http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153156/define-vs-const-in-objective-c/11154217 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024318/why-do-most-c-developers-use-define-instead-of-const/4024634

Comment: The lint error is probably fixed by changing `char` to `char const`

Comment: @Vovanium Those links are completely unrelated. He is asking why Lint keeps giving him very strange errors.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to bandwagon down-vote this. There is nothing in this code which will prevent it from compiling, the question is about why the static analysis tool gives strange error messages.

Comment: @Lundin these links was related (in previous version)

Comment: @Vovanium No, they were only related to the previous weird title, not to the contents of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assignment of string literal to variable

That is a horrible error message. I'm curious about what Lint thinks string literals are good for, if we cannot assign them to variables... It should say something like: "assigning string literal to a non-constant pointer".

> Attempt to cast away const (or volatile)

The warning is incorrect. Again, it should tell you that the pointer variable needs to be `const`.

To sum it up, you get those errors because your static analyser tool is bad.

---

Explanation:

String literals in C are character arrays, `char []`. They are unfortunately not treated as constant type `const char[]` by the language. This is a defect in the C language, because if you attempt a write access of a string literal, then it leads to undefined behaviour and the program might crash and burn. So you *must* treat string literals as if they were const arrays, even though they are not.

Therefore, it is good practice to always declare pointers to string literals as `const char*`.

In the case of Lint, it seems to treat string literals as if they were `const char[]`, which they are not. Therefore it gives you incorrect errors instead of pointing out the actual problem.

Answer (score 8):

A macro is a name given to a fragment of code. Wherever the name occurs in the source file, it is replaced by the code fragment. Macro definitions are directives to the C preprocessor. They are not statements in the sense that they are not `executed`. They are not even there after the preprocessing stage and hence generate no assembly code.

`MAXSTR` is a macro which is replaced by the string literal `"Maximum number reached"`. String literal are read-only and it's undefined behaviour to try to modify them. Therefore, you should make the pointer `const` qualified.

```
#define MAXSTR "Maximum number reached"

const char *str = MAXSTR;  // make the pointer const
```

Comment: I tried with const char* str then error is: Attempt to cast away const (or volatile)

Comment: @kapilddit You have to initialize `const` objects, i.e., define and assign them in the same statement. You cannot define and then assign it later in a separate statement.

Comment: @ajay `#define MAXSTR "Maximum number reached"` `const char *str = MAXSTR;`. Why would this give an error? I am still not sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the string, just make sure it has enough space:

```
#define MAXSTR "Maximum number reached"

char str[100];

strcpy(str, MAXSTR);
```